# React+Laravel: Nivo Slider does not works properly with React Router based navigation

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am creating an app using React and Laravel. I am stuck with the navigation part. I am loading the main.js file (containing the nivo-slider code) in index.blade.php file.

```
<body class="home home-4">
    <!-- React App Container -->
    <div class="all">
        <div id="app"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- App JS -->
    <script src="{{URL::asset('js/app.js')}}" ></script>

    <!-- Vendor JS -->
    <script src="{{URL::asset('/libs/jquery/jquery.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{URL::asset('/libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{URL::asset('/libs/jquery.countdown/jquery.countdown.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{URL::asset('/libs/nivo-slider/js/jquery.nivo.slider.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{URL::asset('/libs/owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{URL::asset('/libs/slider-range/js/tmpl.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{URL::asset('/libs/slider-range/js/jquery.dependClass-0.1.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{URL::asset('/libs/slider-range/js/draggable-0.1.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{URL::asset('/libs/slider-range/js/jquery.slider.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{URL::asset('/libs/elevatezoom/jquery.elevatezoom.js')}}"></script>

    <!-- Template JS -->
    <script src="{{URL::asset('js/main.js')}}"></script>

</body>
```

Following is my App Component containing react-router.

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

const Router = require('react-router-dom').BrowserRouter;
const Route = require('react-router-dom').Route;
const Switch = require('react-router-dom').Switch;

// var Nav = require('./Nav');
var Home = require('./components/Home');
var About = require('./components/About');
var Contact = require('./components/Contact');

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <div className="container">         
            <Route path="/" exact component={Home}></Route>
            <Route path="/home" component={Home}></Route>
            <Route path="/about" component={About}></Route>
            <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}></Route>
        </div>
    </Router>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Problem is with the navigation on Home component. When the app is loaded for the first time, it renders Nivo Slider properly. But when I click on any of the navigation link and navigate back to Home, Nivo Slider breaks.

Home Component:

```
........ // Some code here
class Home extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <Header />
                <div id="content" className="site-content">
                    <div className="section slideshow">
                        <div className="container">
                            <div className="tiva-slideshow-wrapper">
                                <div id="tiva-slideshow" className="nivoSlider">
                                    <Link to="#">
                                        <img className="img-responsive" src="img/slideshow/home4-slideshow-1.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image" />
                                    </Link>
                                    <Link to="#">
                                        <img className="img-responsive" src="img/slideshow/home4-slideshow-2.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image" />
                                    </Link>
                                    <Link to="#">
                                        <img className="img-responsive" src="img/slideshow/home4-slideshow-3.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image" />
                                    </Link>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   ........... // More Code to go
```

As per my understanding, somehow it is not able to load main.js due to which the slider is misbehaving.

Slider section at first load:

```
<div class="section slideshow">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="tiva-slideshow-wrapper">
            <div id="tiva-slideshow" class="nivoSlider">
                <a href="/" class="nivo-imageLink" style="display: block;">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/slideshow/home4-slideshow-1.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image" style="width: 1540px; visibility: hidden;">
                </a>
                <a href="/" class="nivo-imageLink" style="display: none;">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/slideshow/home4-slideshow-2.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image" style="width: 1540px; visibility: hidden;">
                </a>
                <a href="/" class="nivo-imageLink" style="display: none;">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/slideshow/home4-slideshow-3.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image" style="width: 1540px; visibility: hidden;">
                </a>
                <img class="nivo-main-image" src="img/slideshow/home4-slideshow-1.jpg" style="display: inline; width: 1540px; height: 686px;">
                <div class="nivo-caption" style="display: none;"></div>
                <div class="nivo-directionNav">
                    <a class="nivo-prevNav">Prev</a>
                    <a class="nivo-nextNav">Next</a>
                </div>
                <!-- Some of the nivo slider code goes here -->
            <div class="nivo-controlNav">
                <a class="nivo-control active" rel="0">1</a>
                <a class="nivo-control" rel="1">2</a>
                <a class="nivo-control" rel="2">3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Slider section after navigating:

```
<div class="section slideshow">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="tiva-slideshow-wrapper">
            <div id="tiva-slideshow" class="nivoSlider">
                <a href="/">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/slideshow/home4-slideshow-1.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image">
                </a>
                <a href="/">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/slideshow/home4-slideshow-2.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image">
                </a>
                <a href="/">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/slideshow/home4-slideshow-3.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **loadjs package** and call it in **componentDidMount()** to load the libraries after routing. Check out the below snippet for reference.

```
componentDidMount() {
    loadjs('js/main.js', function() {
        console.log('Test');
    });
}
```